# Handle Multiple Filters in Java -MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, filter

There are three filters Class, Section and Date. Now there are seven possibilities:

1- User inputs Class

2-)User inputs Section

3-)User inputs Date

4-) User inputs Date and Class

and so on...

I have written the following code to handle these possibilites in java:

```
if( mySection.equals("0") && myClass.equals("0") && ( FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0 || TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0    ) )
        {
        out.println("Note: Please provide valid filteration attributes. Atleast one filter is required.");
        return;
        }



        if( !mySection.equals("0") && myClass.equals("0") && ( FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0 || TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0    ) )
        {
            Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and st.section='"+mySection+"'";
        }

        if( !mySection.equals("0") && !myClass.equals("0") && ( FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0 || TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0    ) )
        {
            Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and st.section='"+mySection+"' and st.level='"+myClass+"' ";
        }


        if( mySection.equals("0") && !myClass.equals("0") && ( FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0 || TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0    ) )
        {
            Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and st.level='"+myClass+"' ";
        }


        if( mySection.equals("0") && myClass.equals("0") && ( !(FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0) && !(TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0)    ) )
        {
            Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and date_format(time,'%Y-%m-%d %T') between '"+FromDate+"'  and '"+ToDate+"'";
        }


        if( mySection.equals("0") && !myClass.equals("0") && ( !(FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0) && !(TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0)    ) )
        {
            Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and date_format(time,'%Y-%m-%d %T') between '"+FromDate+"'  and '"+ToDate+"' and st.level='"+myClass+"'";
        }


        if( !mySection.equals("0") && myClass.equals("0") && ( !(FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0) && !(TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0)    ) )
        {
            Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and date_format(time,'%Y-%m-%d %T') between '"+FromDate+"'  and '"+ToDate+"' st.section='"+mySection+"'";
        }


        if( !mySection.equals("0") && !myClass.equals("0") && ( !(FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0) && !(TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0)    ) )
        {
            Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and date_format(time,'%Y-%m-%d %T') between '"+FromDate+"'  and '"+ToDate+"' and st.section='"+mySection+"' and st.level='"+myClass+"'";
        }
```

Here's the issue, the minute I add another filter, these possibilities increase drastically, hence more queries and handling. 
In order to handle this efficiently either by JAVA or MYSQL, there must be a way.

A generic sql statement for this case ?

A library in JAVA to handle multiple input queries ?

Something or another...

What can be possibly done to handle this case with as less code as possible (considering the filters might add on) ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, after giving it a thought for some while I arrived at a solution. Here's the generic single query that solves this issue:

```
 if( mySection.equals("0") && myClass.equals("0") && ( FDate.trim().compareTo("")==0 || TDate.trim().compareTo("")==0    ) )
        {
        out.println("Note: Please provide valid filteration attributes. Atleast one filter is required.");
        return;
        }


        Query = "select st.rollno, concat(st.firstname,' ',st.midname,' ',st.lastname), st.level, st.section, st.rfidtag, sc.schoolname, sa.time, date_format(sa.time,'%T') from AAV.studentattendence sa, AAV.Students st, AAV.Schools sc where sa.studentindexptr=st.indexptr and sc.indexptr=st.schoolindexptr and ( '0'='"+mySection+"' or st.section='"+mySection+"') and ('0'='"+myClass+"' or st.level='"+myClass+"') and (  (' 00:00:00'='"+FromDate+"' and ' 23:59:59'='"+ToDate+"')  or (date_format(time,'%Y-%m-%d %T') between '"+FromDate+"'  and '"+ToDate+"' )  )";


executeQuery(Query);
```

When treated as an expression, that resolves to true on default value i.e '0' in my case, the query becomes generic and we can add as many filter clauses as required.